# R returns the same number of rows after subsetting but clearly deletes rows

Tags: r, subset

Basically I have a matrix with 24028 rows and I want to extract a subset of this matrix that meets a certain condition. I use:

```
Sin <- actulab[actulab[,"Atteint_Limite"] == "0",]
```

Here's what I get when I use

```
tail(Sin)

      INDEX Atteint_Limite Limite Sev_cen FRANC ANNEE MOISSIN MONTBATI
24019 24019              0  50000   16216   500     7      12   281000
24021 24021              0  50000   18003   500     7      12   182500
24024 24024              0  50000    3126   500     7      12   224500
24025 24025              0  10000    1850   500     7      11   142500
24027 24027              0  40000   25494   500     7      12   197000
24028 24028              0  10000    9314   500     7      12   147000
```

You can clearly see that there is a jump between 24019, 24021 and 24025 and 24027 therefore it extracted the right data however it seems that the number of rows did not change. Can someone please explain why.

Also, is it possible to fix this problem?

Thank you

PS: when I use dim(Sin) I get

```
 dim(Sin)
[1] 18547    14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem. Look at `nrow(Sin)`. You should see that is has fewer rows after subsetting.

The first column in the output is the "row name". It is not a cumulative index that tells you how many rows there are. Row names are preserved after subsetting (ie they will not change). So if the last row is included in the subset, it will still have the same row name.

Comment: Is there any way to change the name of the rows ?

Comment: Is there a reason that matters? You can set them with `rownames()<-`

Comment: Mostly esthetical purposes, Thank you!

Comment: @Charles remember to select the tick on this answer if it fixes your issue